# Could a lazy val be tail-recursive?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

```
lazy val seq: Unit = {
  println("a")
  seq
}
```

Can we call the expression above tail-recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could argue in that sense, yes - when evaluated, `seq` will recursively evaluate itself, and its evaluation is the last action that is performed.

Regardless of whether this can be called tail-recursive, though, there doesn't seem to be much of a point to it. There is no exit condition nor, if you try and keep your code purely functional, can there be one: there is no parameter, which means that there is no "state" to pass to deeper evaluations and nothing to test against to break the recursion.

Also, if it is indeed tail-recursive, it's not a form of tail recursion that is recognised or supported by Scala - evaluate `seq` and you get a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.annotation.tailrec

scala>   @tailrec
     |   def abc(a: Int): Int = a + abc(a+1)
<console>:10: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method abc: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
         def abc(a: Int): Int = a + abc(a+1)

scala>   @tailrec
     |   lazy val seq: Unit = {println("a"); seq}
seq: Unit = <lazy>

scala> seq
aa
a
...
```

(Please forgive, or correct, some naming error)

At the best of my knowledge, tail recursion happens when you don't need to go up the stack to get previous partial results, in my example `abc`  is called recursively but you do need to go up the stack to get previous results (`a + abc(a + 1)`), if it was `abc(a+1)` it would have been a tail recursive function:

```
scala>   @tailrec
     |   def abc(a: Int): Int = abc(a+1)
abc: (a: Int)Int

scala> abc(0)
  ...
```

Your `val` definition doesn't need to go up the stack since there's no operation that needs to be combined with the partial results accumulated during the stacking.

Comment: Applying `@tailrec` on a `lazy val` doesn't work as of scala 2.11.1. I get the following warning: _no valid targets for annotation on lazy value seq - it is discarded unused._

Comment: It makes sense since as you noted `tailrec` really works only on `def`s, anyway I tested the above code on Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I tried to define a non tail recursive val so : `@tailrec lazy val seq: Int = {println("a"); 1 + seq}` and I got this error `<console>:10: error: lazy vals are not tailcall transformed`, but it _works_ for tail recursive vals (even if it's not really applied).

Comment: Hey, I think you are talking about tail recursive optimize in scala. Do you think the form I mentioned is tail recursive, regardless it can be optimized or not ?

Comment: @jilen theoretically I would say yes since, still theoretically, you don't need to fetch partial results going down the stack calls, practically nothing happens as shown on other answers.